# SharePoint 2010 Asynchronous Updates breaks Datepicker for Inline Editing

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, asynchronous, datepicker, reload

The question is two sections to address current problem and look at a possible work around.

**Current Problem - Asynchronous**

I am using the DVWP webpart with inline editing enabled. There are several date fields that have the javascript datepicker box. When I enable Asynchronous Update the datepicker icon appears, but the javascript to activate the box fails.The error is just "Object Expected" with no good reference back to the code.

Is there a solution/fix to get the date picker working again?

**Work Around - JavaScript**

As a workaround I was trying to use location.reload javascript, but the issue is because of the inline editing the page is treated as a form and I get the ubiquitous "Retry or Cancel" prompt each time the page tries to refresh (which the user finds very annoying).  Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("timedRefresh(60000)");
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
```

So if I can't fix the asynchronous problem above, is there some kind of modified location.reload script I can use that will omit the prompt for 'Retry' or 'Cancel', such as this one line of code that was recommended, but I'm unable to get to work with a timeout length:

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location;
```

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout expects a function to execute, not a string of javascript code.

This line:
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);

Should be:
setTimeout(function(){location.reload(true);}, timeoutPeriod);